# Loading schema from QRC file: Error XSDError in Unknown location, at line 1, column 0: Premature end of document

Tags: xml, qt, xsd, schema

I have an XSD schema file (ANSCII, CRLF line terminators). My software runs on Linux with Qt 5.4.

The file is stored inside a QRC file under the prefix `/`, which means that access to it should be possible when calling `:/myschema.xsd`.

In the constructor of my class I do:

```
MyClass::MyClass(QObject* parent)
 : QObject(parent)
{
  QXmlSchema schema;
  this->validSchema = schema.load(QUrl(":/myschema.xsd"));

  // ...
}
```

It is a simple check if the XSD schema is valid to later use my `QXmlSchemaValidator` class member (in case it is valid) for checking HTTP GET requests in XML format.

However when the `schema.load(...)` is executed I get

> Error XSDError in Unknown location, at line 1, column 0: Premature end of document.

Now using [a online validator](http://www.utilities-online.info/xsdvalidation/) I got three things straight:

- the XSD is well formed and valid
- the XML is well formed
- the XML is invalid when validated against the XSD

So basically this means that the XSD schema I have at my disposal is garbage BUT I'm still interested why the `QXmlSchema::load()` gives me this error especially since according to the online tool the XSD is ok.

Here is the XSD schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:element name="Err">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:complexContent>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:anyType">
                    <xs:attribute name="code" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
                    <xs:attribute name="text" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
                    <xs:attribute name="level" default="E">
                        <xs:simpleType>
                            <xs:restriction base="xs:NMTOKEN">
                                <xs:enumeration value="W"/>
                                <xs:enumeration value="M"/>
                                <xs:enumeration value="E"/>
                            </xs:restriction>
                        </xs:simpleType>
                    </xs:attribute>
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:complexContent>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="Start">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="Station"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="Dest">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="Station"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="StartT">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:complexContent>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:anyType">
                    <xs:attribute name="time" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
                    <xs:attribute name="date" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:complexContent>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="EndT">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:complexContent>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:anyType">
                    <xs:attribute name="time" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
                    <xs:attribute name="date" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:complexContent>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="RFlags">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:complexContent>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:anyType">
                    <xs:attribute name="b" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
                    <xs:attribute name="f" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
                    <xs:attribute name="maxF" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:attribute name="maxB" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:attribute name="sMode" default="N">
                        <xs:simpleType>
                            <xs:restriction base="xs:NMTOKEN">
                                <xs:enumeration value="N"/>
                                <xs:enumeration value="P"/>
                            </xs:restriction>
                        </xs:simpleType>
                    </xs:attribute>
                    <xs:attribute name="p" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:attribute name="r" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:attribute name="t" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:complexContent>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="ResC">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="Err" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                <xs:element ref="SBRes"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="ver" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
            <xs:attribute name="producer" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
            <xs:attribute name="lang" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
            <xs:attribute name="planId" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:attribute name="periodBegin" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:attribute name="periodEnd" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="SBRes">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="Err" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                <xs:element ref="SBReq"/>
                <xs:element ref="StationInfoTextList" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element ref="JourneyList" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element ref="NextUpdate" minOccurs="0"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="dir" use="required">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:NMTOKEN">
                        <xs:enumeration value="A"/>
                        <xs:enumeration value="D"/>
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:attribute>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="SBReq">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="Start"/>
                <xs:element ref="Dest" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element ref="StartT"/>
                <xs:element ref="EndT" minOccurs="0"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="dir" use="required">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:NMTOKEN">
                        <xs:enumeration value="A"/>
                        <xs:enumeration value="D"/>
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:attribute>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="Date">
        <xs:complexType mixed="true">
            <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="Time">
        <xs:complexType mixed="true">
            <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="Location">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:choice>
                <xs:element ref="Station"/>
                <xs:element ref="Address"/>
                <xs:element ref="Poi"/>
            </xs:choice>
            <xs:attribute name="x" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:attribute name="y" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:attribute name="z" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:attribute name="type" default="WGS84">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:NMTOKEN">
                        <xs:enumeration value="WGS84"/>
                        <xs:enumeration value="HAFAS_GEO"/>
                        <xs:enumeration value="HAFAS_HANNOVER"/>
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:attribute>
            <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="Station">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="ExternalId"/>
                <xs:element ref="HafasName"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="ebhfnumber" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:attribute name="ebhfname" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="Address">
        <xs:complexType mixed="true">
            <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="Poi">
        <xs:complexType mixed="true">
            <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="ExternalId">
        <xs:complexType mixed="true">
            <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            <xs:attribute name="pooluic" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="HafasName">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="Text" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="Text">
        <xs:complexType mixed="true">
            <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            <xs:attribute name="lang">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:NMTOKEN">
                        <xs:enumeration value="FR"/>
                        <xs:enumeration value="MACRO"/>
                        <xs:enumeration value="EN"/>
                        <xs:enumeration value="DE"/>
                        <xs:enumeration value="NO"/>
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:attribute>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="NamedValue">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:complexContent>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:anyType">
                    <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
                    <xs:attribute name="value" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:complexContent>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="ServiceDaysList">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="ServiceDays" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="ServiceDays">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="ServiceBits" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element ref="RegularServiceText" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element ref="IrregularServiceText" minOccurs="0"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="ServiceBits">
        <xs:complexType mixed="true">
            <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="RegularServiceText">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="Text" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="IrregularServiceText">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="Text" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="Attribute">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="AttributeCode" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element ref="AttributeVariant" minOccurs="0"  maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="priority" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:attribute name="type" default="NORMAL">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:NMTOKEN">
                        <xs:enumeration value="NAME"/>
                        <xs:enumeration value="OPERATOR"/>
                        <xs:enumeration value="EXTERNALID"/>
                        <xs:enumeration value="NUMBER"/>
                        <xs:enumeration value="CATEGORY"/>
                        <xs:enumeration value="INTERNALCATEGORY"/>
                        <xs:enumeration value="NORMAL"/>
                        <xs:enumeration value="DIRECTION"/>
                        <xs:enumeration value="DIRECTIONFLAG"/>
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:attribute>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="AttributeCode">
        <xs:complexType mixed="true">
            <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="AttributeVariant">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="Text" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="type" default="NORMAL">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:NMTOKEN">
                        <xs:enumeration value="LONG"/>
                        <xs:enumeration value="SHORT"/>
                        <xs:enumeration value="NORMAL"/>
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:attribute>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="Duration">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="Time"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="ParameterList">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="NamedValue" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="FromText">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="Text" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="ToText">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="Text" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="Product">
        <xs:complexType mixed="true">
            <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:attribute name="image" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="Departure">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="BasicStop"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="Arrival">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="BasicStop"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="MainStop">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="BasicStop"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="BasicStop">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="Location"/>
                <xs:element ref="Arr" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element ref="Dep" minOccurs="0"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="type" default="NORMAL">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:NMTOKEN">
                        <xs:enumeration value="VIRTUAL"/>
                        <xs:enumeration value="NORMAL"/>
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:attribute>
            <xs:attribute name="index" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="Platform">
        <xs:complexType mixed="true">
            <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="Arr">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="Time"/>
                <xs:element ref="Delay" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element ref="Platform" minOccurs="0"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="getOut" default="YES">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:NMTOKEN">
                        <xs:enumeration value="YES"/>
                        <xs:enumeration value="NO"/>
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:attribute>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="Dep">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="Time"/>
                <xs:element ref="Delay" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element ref="Platform" minOccurs="0"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="getIn" default="YES">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:NMTOKEN">
                        <xs:enumeration value="YES"/>
                        <xs:enumeration value="NO"/>
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:attribute>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="JourneyList">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:element ref="Journey"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="Journey">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="JourneyAttributeList"/>
                <xs:element ref="MainStop"/>
                <xs:element ref="Product"/>
                <xs:element ref="PassList" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element ref="ServiceDaysList" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element ref="InfoTextList" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element ref="LastRTInfo" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element ref="JProg" minOccurs="0"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="trainId" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
            <xs:attribute name="reachability" default="UNKNOWN">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:NMTOKEN">
                        <xs:enumeration value="GUARANTEED"/>
                        <xs:enumeration value="POSSIBLE"/>
                        <xs:enumeration value="NOT_POSSIBLE"/>
                        <xs:enumeration value="UNKNOWN"/>
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:attribute>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="JourneyAttributeList">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:element ref="JourneyAttribute"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="JourneyAttribute">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="Attribute"/>
                <xs:element ref="ServiceDays" minOccurs="0"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="from" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:attribute name="to" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="PassList">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:element ref="BasicStop"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="Delay">
        <xs:complexType mixed="true">
            <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="StationInfoTextList">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:element ref="StationInfoText"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="StationInfoText">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="Station"/>
                <xs:element ref="InfoTextList" minOccurs="0"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="InfoTextList">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:element ref="InfoText"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="InfoText">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:complexContent>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:anyType">
                    <xs:attribute name="textL" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:attribute name="text" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:attribute name="textS" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:attribute name="link" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:attribute name="priority" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:complexContent>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="NextUpdate">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:complexContent>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:anyType">
                    <xs:attribute name="time" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
                    <xs:attribute name="date" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:complexContent>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="LastRTInfo">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:complexContent>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:anyType">
                    <xs:attribute name="time" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
                    <xs:attribute name="date" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:complexContent>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="JProg">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Train based realtime information</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element ref="JStatus"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="JStatus">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Possible values are: FAILURE - train failure via real time.  NEW or  ADDITIONAL - identifies addtional train. REPLACEMENT - identifies alternative train.  REDIRECTION - one or several additional stops and/or contrary some stops can not be served. PARTIAL_FAILURE - a part of a track can not be served.   PARTIAL_ACTIVATION , REDIRECTION_FAILURE,  REPLACEMENT_REDIRECTION are reserverd for future use. SCHEDULED - train is in time</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: have you tried loading the schema from a local file rather than qrc?

Comment: Frankly no, but I don't see how this will change things. I have other resources that I'm loading from another QRC file and there things work fine (no XSD file though).

Comment: You may give it a try.
Sometimes I have experienced problems when loading some resources directly into Qt classes and I solved copying the file from resources to filesystem, then loading it

Comment: @Giancarlo Sorry for the delay. It seems that loading the XSD with `QUrl::fromLocalFile()` loads the schema correctly. This is rather annoying since I really want to include the schema not as an external file but as part of the binary of my application.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think your problem is the resource path.

Using your schema file, placed in the same qrc path, I get the same error.

The problem disappears using

```
schema.load(QUrl("qrc:/myschema.xsd"));
```